# CSS animation is blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

At the moment im busy trying to get my navbar animation to work properly. But it just wont do it.

```
.headroom {
transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
will-change: transform;
}
.headroom--pinned {
transform: translateY(0%);
}
.headroom--unpinned {
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

The Problem:
When i put all my data in jsfiddle it works! - https://jsfiddle.net/go8442kr/ the navbar is animated

But on my live page (1:1 same code) it doesnt work.
http://1lvlup.com/test2/

Any Ideas on this?

Comment: Please, be specific!!

Comment: @PrateekAgrawal The ease-in transition works for him/her in the fiddle but not on the actual live site

Comment: How could i be more specific? The code works in jsfiddle but not on my own page..

Comment: it's the `.headroom--unpinned{ display: none }` you can't transition display modes

Comment: @Thomas Yes! You are right, now its fixed :) Thank you so much. If you add you comment as a answer i can select it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides the showed styles, the CSS on your page also contains

```
.headroom--unpinned {
  display: none
}
```

wich you don't and can't transition, that interferes with your effect